# RegionPlot not working but DensityPlot of the sign of the function works

Tags: plotting

I have the following ugly thing:

```
DetAQ = 1/(u0 (-1 + v0^2 Subscript[r, 1]))
     Q \[Delta] (-2 D u0 (1 + 6 (-1 + u0) u0) - 
      2 v0 (1 + 6 (-1 + v0) v0) - 
      2 D u0 (1 + 6 (-1 + u0) u0) v0^2 Subscript[r, 1] + 
      2 v0^3 (1 + 6 (-1 + v0) v0) Subscript[r, 1] + 
      2 D u0^2 Subscript[r, 2] + 
      12 D (-1 + u0) u0^3 Subscript[r, 2] + 
      2 D u0^2 v0^2 Subscript[r, 1] Subscript[r, 2] + 
      12 D (-1 + u0) u0^3 v0^2 Subscript[r, 1] Subscript[r, 2]) + (1/(
   u0 (-1 + v0^2 Subscript[r, 1])))
   Q^3 \[Delta] (-4 D u0 (1 + 3 (-1 + u0) u0 + 
         3 (-1 + v0) v0) \[Delta] Subscript[\[Gamma], u] + 
      4 D u0 v0^2 (1 + 3 (-1 + u0) u0 + 
         3 (-1 + v0) v0) \[Delta] Subscript[r, 1] Subscript[\[Gamma], 
       u]) + 1/(u0 (-1 + v0^2 Subscript[r, 1]))
     Q^2 \[Delta] (-4 D u0 (1 + 6 (-1 + u0) u0) (1 + 
         6 (-1 + v0) v0) \[Delta] + 
      4 D u0 (1 + 6 (-1 + u0) u0) v0^2 (1 + 
         6 (-1 + v0) v0) \[Delta] Subscript[r, 1] - 
      D u0 Subscript[\[Gamma], u] - v0 Subscript[\[Gamma], u] - 
      D u0 v0^2 Subscript[r, 1] Subscript[\[Gamma], u] + 
      v0^3 Subscript[r, 1] Subscript[\[Gamma], u] + 
      D u0^2 Subscript[r, 2] Subscript[\[Gamma], u] + 
      D u0^2 v0^2 Subscript[r, 1] Subscript[r, 2] Subscript[\[Gamma], 
       u]) + (Q^4 \[Delta] (-D u0 \[Delta] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Gamma]\), \(u\), \(2\)]\) + 
      D u0 v0^2 \[Delta] Subscript[r, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Gamma]\), \(u\), \(2\)]\)))/(
   u0 (-1 + v0^2 Subscript[r, 1])) ;
```

I define a function for plotting and taking care of some of the parameters:

```
ForPlotting2D[Q_, u0_, v0_] = 
  DetAQ /. Subscript[r, 1] -> 5.0 /. Subscript[r, 2] -> 0 /. 
      D -> 0.516 /. \[Delta] -> 0.002 /. 
    Subscript[\[Gamma], u] -> 1 /. Subscript[\[Gamma], v] -> 1;
```

Now I want to plot the region that satisfies the following properties:

1. In the $(u_0, v_0) \in [0,1] \times [0,1]$ plane
2. The function `ForPlotting2D` is negative at `Q^*` such that `Q^*` is the solution to `df/dQ = 0`
3. `Q^*` is positive

I try to do this as follows:

```
QStar[u0_, v0_] = Solve[D[ForPlotting2D[Q, u0, v0], Q] == 0, Q];
MyList[u0_, v0_] := {QStar[u0, v0][[1]][[1]][[2]], 
   QStar[u0, v0][[2]][[1]][[2]], QStar[u0, v0][[3]][[1]][[2]]};
QS[u0_?NumericQ, v0_?NumericQ] := 
  Cases[MyList[u0, v0], s_ /; Im[s] == 0];
```

And finally to plot:

```
DensityPlot[
 Sign[ForPlotting2D[QS[u0, v0], u0, v0]], {u0, 0, 1}, {v0, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
DensityPlot[Sign[QS[u0, v0]], {u0, 0, 1}, {v0, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

This gives the following ugly plots showing the two regions specified in 2 and 3 above, but I have no way of getting their intersection.

[image]
[image]

On the other hand, if I run

```
RegionPlot[QS[u0, v0] > 0, {u0, 0, 1}, {v0, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

I get... nothing. An empty plot. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D.html) is the built-in function for partial differentiation and should not be used as a user-defined variable/parameter.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I missed that, the notebook is full of partial differentiation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the way I was picking out the positive roots, here's the solution:

```
ForPlotting2D[Q_, u0_, v0_] = 
  DetAQ /. Subscript[r, 1] -> 5.0 /. Subscript[r, 2] -> 0 /. 
      D -> 1/3 /. \[Delta] -> 0.0021 /. 
    Subscript[\[Gamma], u] -> 1 /. Subscript[\[Gamma], v] -> 1;

QStar[u0_, v0_] = Solve[D[ForPlotting2D[Q, u0, v0], Q] == 0 , Q ];
QS[u0_?NumericQ, v0_?NumericQ] := 
  Select[QStar[u0, v0], #[[1]][[2]] > 0 &][[1]][[1]][[2]];
```

Now this will give the intersection of both regions.

```
RegionPlot[
 ForPlotting2D[QS[u0, v0], u0, v0] < 0, {u0, 0, 1}, {v0, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]